# Can't find any way to close a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in python scrapy to get different `ids` and its corresponding `names` from a webpage. When I execute my script, I can see that the result are rightly coming through and I'm getting a data filled in csv file. I'm using python 3.6, so when I go fo scrapy's built-in command (meant to write data in a csv file), I always get a csv file with blank lines in every alternate row. However, I tried the following to serve the purpose and it does it's job. Now, It produces a csv file fixing blank line issues.

My question: how can I close the csv file when the job is done?

This is my try so far:

```
import scrapy, csv

class SuborgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "suborg"

    start_urls = ['https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/en/sanctions/1267/aq_sanctions_list/summaries?type=All&page={}'.format(page) for page in range(0,7)]

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open("output.csv", "w", newline="")

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"views-table")]//tbody//tr'):
            idnum = item.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"views-field-field-reference-number")]/text()').extract()[-1].strip()
            name = item.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"views-field-title")]//span[@dir="ltr"]/text()').extract()[-1].strip()
            yield{'ID':idnum,'Name':name}
            writer = csv.writer(self.file)
            writer.writerow([idnum,name])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close the actual file instead:

You can call it in the `closed()` method which is automatically called when the spider is closed.

```
def closed(self, reason):
    self.file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @nosklo. I knew that as well. However, the problem is I can't understand as to where exactly I should place that suggested line within my scraper.

Comment: How this `reason` parameter can be correlated with other method? I meant the use case. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU the scrapy framework provides the `reason` parameter which contains the reason the spider was closed. It is not needed in this particular spider so it can be ignored, but it can be useful for other programs. More details in scrapy docs https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed